# Improving slow MariaDB query performance

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, query-optimization

I have what seems to be a fairly straightforward query, but it is super slow and I would like to improve its performance if I can.

```sql
SELECT `contacts`.`unit_id`, `contacts`.`owner_id`, `units`.`description`, 
  `units`.`address`, `owners`.`name`, `owners`.`email`, COUNT(*) AS contact_count
FROM `contacts`
LEFT JOIN `units` ON `contacts`.`unit_id` = `units`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `owners` ON `contacts`.`owner_id` = `owners`.`id`
WHERE `owners.group_id` = 6
  AND `contacts`.`checkin` BETWEEN '2021-10-01 00:00:00' AND '2021-10-31 23:59:59'
GROUP BY `units`.`id`
ORDER BY `contact_count` DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

I'm just trying to get the units with the most contacts in a given date range, and belonging to a certain group of owners.

```
+------+-------------+----------+--------+--------------------------------------------------+---------------------------+---------+-------------------------+------+---------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table    | type   | possible_keys                                    | key                       | key_len | ref                     | rows | Extra                           |
+------+-------------+----------+--------+--------------------------------------------------+---------------------------+---------+-------------------------+------+---------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | owners   | ref    | PRIMARY,owners_group_id_foreign                  | owners_group_id_foreign   | 4       | const                   | 1133 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | contacts | ref    | contacts_checkin_index,contacts_owner_id_foreign | contacts_owner_id_foreign | 4       | appdb.owners.id         | 1145 | Using where                     |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | units    | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                          | PRIMARY                   | 4       | appdb.contacts.unit_id  |    1 |                                 |
+------+-------------+----------+--------+--------------------------------------------------+---------------------------+---------+-------------------------+------+---------------------------------+
```

As near as I can tell, everything that should be indexed is:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `contacts` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `owner_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `unit_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `terminal_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `checkin` datetime NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `contacts_checkin_index` (`checkin`),
  KEY `contacts_unit_id_foreign` (`unit_id`),
  KEY `contacts_terminal_id_foreign` (`terminal_id`),
  KEY `contacts_owner_id_foreign` (`owner_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `contacts_unit_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`unit_id`) REFERENCES `units` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `contacts_terminal_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`terminal_id`) REFERENCES `terminals` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `contacts_owner_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`owner_id`) REFERENCES `owners` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=25528530 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

The `contacts` table currently has about 10 million rows, and this query takes about 4 minutes to run. Is this anything that can be improved significantly or am I just bumping up against limitations of my hardware at this point?

Comment: The query is malformed and can only run in MySQL 5.7.5 or older. In sum, any column not included in the `GROUP  BY` clause should appear aggregated in the `SELECT` list. Please fix this, since the results of the current query are somewhat random at the moment.

Comment: There's another issue: The outer join `LEFT JOIN owners` is silently converted into an inner join by the engine due to the predicate `owners.group_id = 6`. Do you want an outer join or an inner join?

Comment: @TheImpaler the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` SQL mode is not enabled by default in MariaDB.

Comment: Thanks for providing (1) the real query, (2) the Explain, (3) CREATE TABLE, (4) table size. That made it "easy" to answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  sub.unit_id, sub.owner_id, u.`description`, u.`address`,
        sub.name, sub.email,
        sub.contact_count
    FROM  
        ( SELECT  c.`unit_id`, c.`owner_id`,
                  o.`name`, o.`email`,
                  COUNT(*) AS contact_count
            FROM  `contacts` AS c
            JOIN  `owners` AS o  ON c.`owner_id` = o.`id`
            WHERE  o.`group_id` = 6
              AND  c.`checkin` >= '2021-10-01'
              AND  c.`checkin` <  '2021-10-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
            GROUP BY  c.`unit_id`
            ORDER BY  `contact_count` DESC
            LIMIT  20 
        ) AS sub
    LEFT JOIN  `units` AS u  ON sub.`unit_id` = u.`id`
    ORDER BY  `contact_count` DESC, sub.unit_id DESC;
```

Notes:

- I turned it inside out in order to hit `units` only 20 times.
- `JOIN owners` cannot be `LEFT JOIN`, so I changed that.
- I changed the `GROUP BY` to avoid using `units` prematurely.
- Possibly the `GROUP BY` is now redundant.
- I changed the date range to make it easier to be generic.
- I augmented the `ORDER BY` to make it deterministic in case of dup counts.
- Notice, below, how "composite" indexes can be helpful.

Indexes that may help:

```
contacts:  INDEX(checkin, unit_id, owner_id)
contacts:  INDEX(owner_id, checkin, unit_id)
owners:  INDEX(group_id, id,  name, email)
```

When adding those, remove any `INDEXes` that start with the same columns.  Example:  `contacts:  INDEX(checkin)`

Comment: I praise the length you went to answer this question. This is one of the cases when you see a lot of answer for a half-baked question. +1 for the effort.

Comment: @TheImpaler - Thanks.  Most of those bullet items are coding "patterns" that I see nearly every day.  The indexes came from a program I am developing (plus hand-checking).

Comment: Just tried this, after fixing a couple of minor errors I'm not seeing any significant change in query time unfortunately. Will see about adding the composite indices over the weekend.

Comment: @miken32 - Sorry about the errors; glad you figured them out.  `LEFT JOIN o` becomes `JOIN o` because `WHERE o.group_id=6` requires the row(s) to exist.

Comment: Well those indices made all the difference. Only a couple of seconds to do the query now. Seems counterintuitive that indices on individual columns don’t help when querying that column with others. Will have to do some reading and see where else I might be able to improve indexing.

Comment: @miken32 - My discussion on such:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql  (I still don't have a good writeup on doing the inside-out trick I pulled with `units`.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, so I can't be sure exactly, but I think the main reason for the slow speed is the number of rows participating in group by.

So, you can try the following method to reduce the number of rows.
(Since I can't test it, I'm not sure if this query will run correctly. I'm just trying to show you a way.)

```
SELECT B.*, `owners`.`name`, `owners`.`email`
FROM (
   SELECT `units`.`id`, MAX(`contacts`.`owner_id`) AS owner_id, `units`.`description`, `units`.`address`, COUNT(*) AS contact_count
   FROM (
        SELECT *
        FROM `contacts`
        WHERE `contacts`.`checkin` BETWEEN '2021-10-01 00:00:00' AND '2021-10-31 23:59:59') as A
   LEFT JOIN `units` ON A.`unit_id` = `units`.`id`
   GROUP BY `units`.`id`) AS B
LEFT JOIN `owners` ON B.`owner_id` = `owners`.`id` AND `owners.group_id` = 6
ORDER BY `contact_count` DESC
LIMIT 20
```

Previously, I have a similar experience that I have to check the number of ad views and page visitors by date and time range,
and in this way, the time was reduced.